# Remove special characters and add a semi colon in a word - Tableau

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I need to remove the special characters from the beginning and the end of each word. But there are few words where it gets tricky. Btw, I am working in tableau.

Word:

```
;#Bank#;Server#;
```

I used

```
REGEXP_REPLACE([Category], "[^0-9a-zA-Z ]+", "")
```

Using this code, the word becomes `BANKSERVER`. I want a comma or a semicolon between `Bank` and `server`. How can I achieve this? Any possible leads would be greatly appreciated.

Actual result:

```
BANKSERVER
```

Expected result:

```
BANK,SERVER
```

or

```
BANK;SERVER
```

Alternatively, If I add a semicolon to the regex code:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE([Category], "[^0-9a-zA-Z ;]+", "")
```

However, the output is as follows:

```
;BANK;SERVER;
```

Comment: A comma or semi-colon?

Comment: Either of the two should be okay.

Comment: What is expected if string is `;#Bank#&&&&&Server#;`?

Comment: Expected string is Bank, server

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Something seems off with this. it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, the quotes are mixed, `REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE([Category], '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]+', ';'), '^(?:\s*;)+\s*|\s*(?:;+\s*)+$|\s*(?:(;)+\s*)+', '$1')`. Does this produce any different output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Now that did work! This is what I was expecting :) Can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE([Category], '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]+', ';'), '^(?:\s*;)+\s*|\s*(?:;+\s*)+$|\s*(?:(;)+\s*)+', '$1')
```

**Details**

- `REGEXP_REPLACE([Category], '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]+', ';')` - replaces all chars but alphanumeric and space with `;` chars
- `REGEXP_REPLACE(..., '^(?:\s*;)+\s*|\s*(?:;+\s*)+$|\s*(?:(;)+\s*)+', '$1')` - removes leading/trailing semi-colons and shrinks 1+ semi-colons with a single semicolon also removing any whitespace.

Comment: You are a rockstar buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Just add semicolon in the character class:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE([Category], "[^0-9a-zA-Z; ]+", "")
//                              here __^
```

Comment: I tried it already and this would result in something like this:

;BANK;


;BANK;SERVER;

Comment: @jinglyhk: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56464321/edit) and add test cases with expected result.

Comment: Edited. Please look at it now!

Comment: so "BANK;SERVER" would be great, but ";BANK;SERVER;" is somehow not because of delimiters at the start/end of the string?  You want the regex _itself_ to somehow invoke `trimStart()` and `trimEnd()` for you?  KISS

Answer (score 0):

**Remove All Special Characters at the End and the Beginning of String and then Replace Separators**

This is similar to Wiktor's solution and borrows his approach to pass through the string twice.

1. First, clean up the string at the beginning and the end using greedy quantifiers with a minimum match of one.

`'(^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([^a-zA-Z0-9]+$)'`

2. Clean the "separator" special characters greedily with a minimum quantifier of 1, replacing with a `,` character.

`'([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)'`

Solution:
`REGEXP_REPLACE (REGEXP_REPLACE([Word], '(^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([^a-zA-Z0-9]+$)', '' ), '([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)' , ',')`

[image]